# Opening an Excel file with Pandas

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to open my Excel sheet on pandas. I've found some interesting online [tutorial](https://marcel-jan.eu/datablog/2019/03/08/showing-a-complex-excel-sheet-whos-boss-with-python-and-pandas/). However, I'm stuck trying to organize my header.

So far, I've following the code:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.width', 300) 
fuel_file = (r'C:\Users\Sarah\Desktop\test\test2.xlsx')
xl = pd.ExcelFile(fuel_file)
print(xl.sheet_names)
fuel_df = xl.parse("Moon", header=[1], index_col=[0,1,2])
print(fuel_df.head())
print(fuel_df.columns)

weeknumbers_list = list(fuel_df.columns)
spacecustomers = fuel_df.iloc[1]

start_position = 0

for weeknr_pos in positions_weeknumbers:
    for pos in range(start_position, weeknr_pos):
        weeknumbers_list[pos] = weeknumbers_list[weeknr_pos]
    start_position = weeknr_pos + 1
    weeknumbers_list[weeknr_pos] = "Remove"

fuel_df.columns = weeknumbers_list
fuel_df.drop("Remove", axis=1, inplace=True)
```

The problem is in :

```
for weeknr_pos in positions_weeknumbers:
```

The error message:

```
**for weeknr_pos in positions_weeknumbers: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable**
```

I don't know how to define `positions_weeknumbers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error "'int' object is not iterable" because "positions_weeknumbers" will be having an int value and you can't iterate an int object.You have to specify int object inside range() function as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.width', 300) 
fuel_file = (r'C:\Users\Sarah\Desktop\test\test2.xlsx')
xl = pd.ExcelFile(fuel_file)
print(xl.sheet_names)
fuel_df = xl.parse("Moon", header=[1], index_col=[0,1,2])
print(fuel_df.head())
print(fuel_df.columns)

weeknumbers_list = list(fuel_df.columns)
spacecustomers = fuel_df.iloc[1]

start_position = 0

for weeknr_pos in range(positions_weeknumbers):
    for pos in range(start_position, weeknr_pos):
        weeknumbers_list[pos] = weeknumbers_list[weeknr_pos]
    start_position = weeknr_pos + 1
    weeknumbers_list[weeknr_pos] = "Remove"

fuel_df.columns = weeknumbers_list
fuel_df.drop("Remove", axis=1, inplace=True)
```